# Having admin inline for model without direct relation or foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

So, I have this these model:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=70, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Photo(Media):
    source = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/gallery/photo')

class Video(Media):
    source = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/gallery/photo')

class Item(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        limit_choices_to={'model__in': ['photo', ]},
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Album(Media):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

How can I have an album admin with photo and video as inline so i can upload photo and video when i created an album ?

When I tried making inline for photo and hook it to album admin, I get error "photo has no foreignkey to album", pretty obvious, from there I think there should be a way to link foreignkey needed by album admin with content object from model item.

Note: I specifically doesn't want an item admin. An item are created at model post save signals.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this works out of the box. But you can use libraries like eg [django-smart-selects-generics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-selects-generic/0.1.0). Depending on your django version you might need to update some files there.

Installation works with:

```
pip install django-smart-selects-generic
```

You also need to have [django-smart-selects](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-selects) installed.

Then add both apps in the settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'smart_selects',
        'smart_generic'  
          )
```

And then in your admin.py you can do:

```
from smart_generic.form_fields import GenericChainedModelChoiceField
from django.forms.models import ModelForm

class TForm(ModelForm):
    object_id = GenericChainedModelChoiceField('content_type','content_type',label=u'Content object',queryset=TargetRelation.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = TargetRelation
        fields = ['target','content_type']


class TRAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TForm

class TRInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TargetRelation
    form = TForm

class PlanetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[TRInline,]
```

Depending on your django version you might need to replace in widgets.py:

```
Media = ChainedSelect.Media
```

by

```
.media = ChainedSelect.Media
```

And in smart_select views.py add:

```
import json as simplejson
```

and replace the return statement by:

```
return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: i see the repo, but i don't know what its doing. No doc too. I only see form, widget and view.